# Gradle: Cannot open cache directory buildSrc (permission denied)

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I'm having an issue with my gradle. I am trying to run bunch of gradle commands one after one and it fails. I'm using **gradle 1.10**

Our build used to work. Everything works but it fails in the final step. I am not sure how to solve this issue:

```
:datageneration:classes
:datageneration:jar
:datageneration:startScripts
:datageneration:installApp

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1 mins 21.803 secs
+ cd webui
+ gradle dist prepopulateData

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not open cache directory buildSrc (/ng/webui/buildSrc/.gradle/noVersion/buildSrc).
> java.io.IOException: Permission denied
```

I have tried:

```
sudo chmod +x -R  777 $WORKSPACE/webui/buildSrc/* //Tried to give 777. 
sudo rm -rf $WORKSPACE/webui/buildSrc/*   //Removed the folder
```

I don't have any clue what can be done. Help would be appreciated.

- R